# Different compiler versions of solidity don't match?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, erc-20, hardhat

I am currently using the '***Hardhat documentation***' to use a correct solidity compiler version, but while precisely compiling my file.sol with `pragma solidity ^0.6.0`, I am still getting an error:

```
module.exports = {
  solidity: {
    version: "0.6.5",
    settings: {
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 1000,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

**Error message**

```
"Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.8.17+commit.8df45f5f.Emscripten.clang) - note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version"
```

It seems that HardHat can't download the compiler, can you help me plz?

Comment: Can you mark as answered if it was helpful ;) @Dingo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes you may want to use a different **compiler** than the one provided. You can find all the different versions in the `solc-bin` repository https://binaries.soliditylang.org/

Currently, there are four ways supported to use a different version of the solidity compiler. ***Remote***, ***Local***, ***NodeModule*** and ***Embedded***

You can change the compiler in your vscode settings or workspace settings you use.

[image]

Then select an specific version to use:

[image]

**NOTE:** May need install one of these extensions for Visual Studio Code:

*`Ethereum Solidity Language`* or *`Solidity and Hardhat support`* by the Hardhat team

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended that Solidity version be locked and specified without the ^(carat) sign, as `pragma solidity 0.6.5`. This ensures that the specific compiler will always be used, using which code is tested most. It also prevents the code from exhibiting any unintended or unexpected behaviors.

Comment: Yes, that's right, as is well, thanks for the support and reinforcement. @Yongjian